# How to fix an .csv file with wrong/different/inconsistent column numbers due to commas within a field

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 60 .xlsx files with 300K-500k rows that I was hoping to read into a df to do some analysis
the problem I'm facing is that when I read the files into a df I get extra columns due to commas within a fields, looking into one of those excel files I encounter the following situation example right into the excel file:

- first row should have for ProductName: "reg (.com,.net)". The 2nd row is fine. The third row the ProductName should be: "reg(.com,.ca,.net)"

```
 ProductName    | Product Code |    Term      | Amnt                                              
 reg (.com.     |      .net)   |     X123     |   12    |     7.99
  wh            |      Y987    |     36       |   5.99  
reg (.com.      |      .net    |    .ca)      |   X123  |    12. | 7.99
```

This situation appears to happen on all most (if not all) the excel files I need to work with.
fixing this manually it's going to take forever given the massive amount of records

Is there a way to fix those rows somehow with python and make them all even somehow?

ps.

1. when I read the files into a dataframe I'm simply using this code:
   I read each excel file into a dataframe which I then store in a list and then I concatenate df's into a single df

```
data_frame_list = []
files_in_folder = glob.glob('drive/MyDrive/partialdataset/*')
#read data into dataframe
for file in files_in_folder:
  data_frame_list.append(pd.read_excel(file))
#concatenate the dataframes
df = pd.concat(data_frame_list)
df
```

2. the original files are .ods which I converted to .xlsx because I was running into memory issues (even reading only one single .ods file) in colab when reading those into a dataframe. when I open the .ods in excel the same issue in the example is shown.

Comment: What code are you using to read these files in?  Maybe it could be modified to address this issue.

Comment: Export the xlsx file with a different separator than a comma.

Comment: It can't be an xlsx file, there is no separator. It should be a csv file, no?

Comment: Why would there be confusion over commas when the column separators appear to be | (pipe)?

Comment: Excel files have no separators, commas or otherwise. What you have is a text file, even if it has a fake Excel extension. `xlsx` is a ZIP package containing well-defined XML files. Cell values are stored in different XML elements. There are no separators

Comment: What is the actual extension and how do you read the files? If you use Pandas `read_excel` would throw complaining that this isn't an Excel file, You'd have to use `read_csv` and specify `|` as the separator.

Comment: How are you reading these files in?  `pandas.read_excel()`?

Comment: If the files are real Excel files, they were probably created by blindly loading a text file in Excel without specifying the correct separator and saving it again as `xlsx`. This would mangle both columns *and* decimal values. It would be a *lot* easier and safer to find the original text files and read them with `read_csv`.

Comment: I experimented with one single .ods file. I save it as csv with a diferrent delimeter (tab) but when I read that with `read_csv(file, sep='\t')` the ProductName field is still splitted in tabs. It seems to me I won't be able to fix the source files, I need to figure out a way to fix propably within the dataframe, row by row maybe.

Comment: @FranciscoCortes Fix the source

Comment: @Fred fixing the source will certainly be ideal but the size of the datasets on those files is massive and I was hoping for a programmatic solution.

Comment: Your problem did not reproduce for me, not when reading an .ods file, nor when reading .xlsx.

Comment: @Сергей Кох, I'm not sure what to say about that, Unfortunately I can't share the original .ods files I was given (which exahust the memory in google collab when read into pd as is) nor the excel files that do end up giving me df but with the extra columns as shown in my example above.

Comment: create a minimal example that reproduces the problem.

Comment: @Сергей Кох
for the memory issue I ran when loading .ods into df, I figure I might have to alter a whole bunch of rows, and I don't have that time. My focus at this time is figuring out if I can find the rows where the extra columns occur and see if I can extract the data into other columns pythonically before deleting the extra columns on those rows, that, for now appeared to be only productive approach.

Comment: thank you @all for your input.. just to clarify about my sample data... the structure shown is just pictorial. There are no '|' pipes separating cells in actual excel file I started working with.

Answer (score 0):

I looked at my data and following @fred advice, I decided to give it a try and fix my source files.
Luckly there was a pattern for those rows that resulted in extra columns, so
what I did was the following

1. I opted not use .xlsx or .ods so I converted my .ods files into .csv files. I used a windows app I found online called GroupDocs.Total Apps for Windows, which allowed for the bulk conversion from my original .ods files to .csv
2. I then use code like the one below to read each .csv file and traverse through each line to a) remove whitespaces (which was a problem a also found in my dataset) and b) fix those rows where there was a cell that included commas causing the uncalled cell split into columns (conditions) and c) re-generate a fixed .csv that I can use for analysis with pandas

```
import csv

#get all the csv's to be fixed from a google drive folder
files_in_folder = glob.glob('drive/MyDrive/Datasets/*.csv')
for file in files_in_folder:
  filename = os.path.basename(file).replace('.csv','')
  #open each .csv file the grab headers and rows and store those in new respectivey lists as we fix the issue when split conditions arise
  new_rows = []
  new_header = []
  with open(file, 'r') as file:
      csvreader = csv.reader(file)
      header = next(csvreader)
      for col in header:
        if len(col)>0:
          new_header.append(col.strip())
      for row in csvreader:
        new_row = []
        #print(row)
        if 'Registration (' in row[10].strip() and ')' in row[11].strip()): 
          #condition 1 that cause split
          new_row.append(row[0].strip()) 
          new_row.append(row[1].strip()) 
          new_row.append(row[2].strip()) 
          new_row.append(row[3].strip()) 
          new_row.append(row[4].strip()) 
          new_row.append(row[5].strip()) 
          new_row.append(row[6].strip()) 
          new_row.append(row[7].strip()) 
          new_row.append(row[8].strip()) 
          new_row.append(row[9].strip()) 
          new_row.append(row[10].strip()+row[11].strip())
          new_row.append(row[12].strip()) 
          new_row.append(row[13].strip()) 
          new_row.append(row[14].strip()) 
          new_row.append(row[15].strip()) 
        elif 'Registration (' in row[10].strip() and ')' in row[12].strip():
          #condition 2 that cause split
          new_row.append(row[0].strip()) 
          new_row.append(row[1].strip()) 
          new_row.append(row[2].strip()) 
          new_row.append(row[3].strip()) 
          new_row.append(row[4].strip()) 
          new_row.append(row[5].strip()) 
          new_row.append(row[6].strip()) 
          new_row.append(row[7].strip()) 
          new_row.append(row[8].strip()) 
          new_row.append(row[9].strip()) 
          new_row.append(row[10].strip()+row[11].strip()+row[12].strip())
          new_row.append(row[13].strip()) 
          new_row.append(row[14].strip()) 
          new_row.append(row[15].strip()) 
          new_row.append(row[16].strip()) 
        elif 'Registration (' in row[10].strip() and ')' in row[13].strip():
          #condition 3 that cause split
          new_row.append(row[0].strip()) 
          new_row.append(row[1].strip()) 
          new_row.append(row[2].strip()) 
          new_row.append(row[3].strip()) 
          new_row.append(row[4].strip()) 
          new_row.append(row[5].strip()) 
          new_row.append(row[6].strip()) 
          new_row.append(row[7].strip()) 
          new_row.append(row[8].strip()) 
          new_row.append(row[9].strip()) 
          new_row.append(row[10].strip()+row[11].strip()+row[12].strip()+row[13].strip())
          new_row.append(row[14].strip()) 
          new_row.append(row[15].strip()) 
          new_row.append(row[16].strip()) 
          new_row.append(row[17].strip()) 
        elif (not ')' in row[11]) and (not ')' in row[12]) and (not ')' in row[13]): #no split registrations rows keep as is
          for item in row:
            if len(item)>0:
              new_row.append(item.strip())
        new_rows.append(new_row)
  #create a new and fixed .csv file and store it in google drive
  new_filename = '/content/drive/MyDrive/Datasets/partialdataset/'+ filename + '_fixed.csv'
  with open(new_filename, 'w', newline="") as file:
      csvwriter = csv.writer(file) 
      csvwriter.writerow(new_header) 
      csvwriter.writerows(new_rows)
```

Now, all rows and headers are aligned, no white space (leading and trail, which was also another problem I found) and now I'm ready to read several properly formatted csv into a single dataframe :)